# Using realloc to store just some values from a vector

Tags: c

I can't understand what is going on.
I have written this test code to test a procedure that i need on another code. I basically want to obtain pointers only to the values different from zero in an array.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int b[10]={0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9};
    int *p;
    int i;
    int count=0;

    p=malloc(0) ;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        if (*(b+i)!=0)
        {
            count++;

            realloc(p,count * sizeof(int));

            *(p + count -1) = *(b + i);

            printf("*(p + %d) = %d\n",count-1,*(p + count -1));
        }

    for (i=0;i<count;i++)
        printf("*(p+%d) = %d\n",i,*(p+i));

    return 0;

}
```

And what happens is that, in the print inside the first "for" cycle, they are printed as i expect, so 1 2 4 7 8 9, but when i print those values a second time, they are sometimes correct, sometimes the first two numbers are totally random.
Does this come from an improper use of realloc?

Comment: You do need to malloc 0. Just assign NULL to p

Comment: you do not use the return value of realloc

Comment: You do not check result oh the realloc

Comment: *"Does this come from an improper use of realloc?"* - Yup. Understanding how the library functions you're calling *work* helps significantly. Worth reading: [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like:

```
int *new_p = realloc(p, count * sizeof(int));
if (new_p != NULL)
    p = new_p;
else {
  free(p);
  return ENOMEM; //or any error
}
```

so that you use the return value of realloc and check the realloc was fine withour leak.